# Avoid using an array for wildcard expansion in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote the following code:

```
join(){
        IFS="$1"
        shift
        echo "$*"
}

FILES=(/tmp/*)
SEPARATED_FILES=$(join , ${FILES[*]})
echo $VAR
```

And it prints the comma separated lists of files in `/tmp` just fine. But I would like to refactor it and eliminate the tmp global variable `FILES` which is an array. I tried the following:

```
SEPARATED_FILES=$(join , ${(/tmp/*)[*]})
echo $VAR
```

But it prints the following error:

```
line 8: ${(/tmp/*)[*]}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can avoid it by doing pass the glob as directly an argument to the function. Note that, the glob results are expanded by the shell before passing to the function. So pass the first argument as the `IFS` you want to set and the second as the glob expression you want to use.

```
join , /tmp/*
```

The glob is expanded to file names before the function is being called.

```
join , /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 /tmp/file3
```

A noteworthy addition to the above would be to use `nullglob` option before calling the function. Because when the glob does not produce any results, the un-expanded string can be safely ignored.

```
shopt -s nullglob
join , /tmp/*
```

and in a command substitution syntax as

```
fileList=$(shopt -s nullglob; join , /tmp/*)
```

---

Couple of takeaways from your good effort.

1. Always apply shell quoting to variables/arrays unless you have a reason not to do so. Doing so preserves the literal value of the contents inside and prevents Word-Splitting from happening
2. Always use lower case names for user-defined variable/function and array names